# Why server created using java socket doesn't not print data send from client (it dislays if client terminate)?

Tags: java, sockets

In example below I created one server which will only print whatever client is writing in a socket. But I am not getting output as client enter data. If client terminate then I can see all the data client inserted in outputstream. I am taking input from console at client and then write that data to server socket.

**Server code:**

```
   public class server {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("waiting");
    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(9999);
    Socket stemp = s.accept();
    System.out.println("read comp");
    InputStream is = stemp.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);

    while(true)
    {
        String str = br.readLine();
        if(str!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        if(str.contains("exit"))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    stemp.close();
    ir.close();
    is.close();
    br.close();
}
}
```

**Client code:**

```
public class client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String ip ="127.0.0.1";
        int port = 9999;
        Socket s1 = new Socket(ip, port);
        OutputStream os = s1.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter ow = new OutputStreamWriter(os);

        BufferedWriter pw = new BufferedWriter(ow);
        pw.write("I am ready");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);
        while(!str.contains("exit"))
        {
            pw.write(str);
            pw.flush();
            str = s.nextLine();
        }
        pw.close();
        os.close();
        ow.close();
        s1.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Real time' has a specific meaning in computing, and this isn't it. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `server`, `br.readLine();` is used, waiting for end-of-line.

In client, you have to send the eol in `pw.write( str + '\n' );`.